# Mail Undelivered - exceeded max time without delivery

Tags: email

I received the following message:

> A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
>   recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:
>   support@beam.ag (Undelivered): 554 5.4.7 [internal] exceeded max time without delivery.

Could you please advise how to avoid such error and what I need to do in order to make it possible for the letter to be received by the above recipient?